# Reorder array based on passed in value

Tags: ruby

If I have this array:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

I have this string:

```
"C"
```

I want to reorder the array to look like this:

```
["C", "A", "B", "D"]
```

So, the passed in string will move the matching element to the front of the list.

Comment: Is the input array always sorted? What if there are multiple matching elements? Are all elements unique? Thanks.

Comment: Good question, for this particular case, there can't be. Yes, all elements are unique.

Comment: What is your desired result when the array is `["A", "B", "C", "D", "C"]` and the string is `"C"`? Aside: don't forget to include @username in your comments so the intended recipient will be notified by SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C']
target = 'C'

a.partition { |e| e==target }.reduce(:+)
  #=> ["C", "C", "A", "B", "D"]
```

or

```
a.select { |e| e==target }.concat(a.reject { |e| e==target })
  #=> ["C", "C", "A", "B", "D"]
```

`a` is not modified.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! `a.partition { |e| e==target }.reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to *sort* the array, this would work:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
a.sort_by.with_index { |e, i| [e == 'C' ? 0 : 1, i] }
#=> ["C", "A", "B", "D"]
```

Otherwise, you can just [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-delete) `'C'` from the array and [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-prepend) it:

```
a.prepend(a.delete('C'))
#=> ["C", "A", "B", "D"]
```

Note that this will modify `a`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have non uniq target string:

```
ary = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "C"]
target = "C"

ary.count(target).times.map{ target } + ary.reject{ |e| e == target }
#=> ["C", "C", "A", "B", "D"]
```

I must find a more elegant way...

```
ary.find_all{ |e| e == target } + ary.tap { |a| a.delete target }
```