# Sorting array with starter inside the array

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

sorry I had issues formulating my question.
to explain it better :

```
I have a = ["alice", "jean", "bob"]
```

Now i want to let the user choose who will start the game.
If its jean, the new array should be like this

```
a = ["jean", "bob", "alice"]
```

So far, this is working :

```
def sort_array_players(array_player, starter)
  sort_array_player = []
  array_player.map do |name|
    if name == starter && name == array_player[0]
      sort_array_player = [array_player[0], array_player[1], array_player[2]]
    elsif name == starter && name == array_player[1]
      sort_array_player = [array_player[1], array_player[2], array_player[0]]
    elsif name == starter && name == array_player[2]
      sort_array_player = [array_player[2], array_player[0], array_player[1]]
    end 
  end 
  puts sort_array_player
end
```

I want to refractor this code but i'm a bit new to ruby, I've spend 2 hours trying to figure out this thing. My guess is that you need to use each.with_index and then create the new array starting by the first one and the following element would be the one with the index of the starter + 1..

Thanks for helping guys

Comment: `array_player.rotate(array_player.index(starter))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233426/5025116

Comment: @rubish Wow ruby is cool. I Think i understand but could you enlight me a bit more ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rubish commented, you can use [Array#rotate](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/rotate) method.

You can use positive integer as `count` parameter to rotate items counter clockwise or negative integers to rotate them clockwise.

```
a = ["alice", "jean", "bob"]
starter = "jean"
count = a.index(starter) # => 1

a.rotate(count) # => ["jean", "bob", "alice"]
```

Comment: There's no need to quote from a method's doc, especially when the method is as straightforward as `Array#rotate`. Rather, just provide the link: "The method [Array#rotate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate) can be used here". Also, your line `a.rotate(-count) # => ["bob", "alice", "jean"]` line is irrelevant and distracting.